# can not open https://localhost:9443/carbon/

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I added `[admin_console.authenticator.saml_sso_authenticator] enable=true` into deployment.toml. I can't open https://localhost:9443/carbon/, my browser always turn to `about:blank#blocked`. Then, I deleted `[admin_console.authenticator.saml_sso_authenticator] enable=true`. Now I can open https://localhost:9443/carbon/ normally.

Can you tell me how to do for it?

Comment: my IS version is 5.14

Comment: I checked for many time. sometime,  it return "Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS."     ----- it seemed that it have related to SSL function?

Answer (score 0):

`assertion_consumer_service_url` and `identity_provider_sso_service_url` have to be added to the deployment.toml file.

```
enable = true
login_page = "/carbon/admin/login.jsp"
assertion_consumer_service_url = "https://localhost:9443/acs"
identity_provider_sso_service_url = "https://localhost:9443/samlsso"
```

You can refer https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/multi-factor-authentication-for-wso2-is-management-console/ for more information.